# JQuery-UI-Autocomplete with JSP not showing anything

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a Country.java class that returns a string formatted in JSON by a library I found from the JSON page.  A JSP I called getCountry.jsp gets that string and just simply prints it out.

My index.jsp has

```
<script>
  $( "#fromCountry" ).autocomplete({
    source: "getCountry.jsp",
    minLength: 2
  });
</script>
```

where fromCountry is the id for a textbox.

I'm completely new to JQuery and for the most part have barely touched javascript, so it's very possible that I did something stupid.

When I visit "/getCountry.jsp?term=B" I get

> [{"value":"Berlin, Germany","label":"Berlin, Germany"},{"value":"Boston, United States of America","label":"Boston, United States of America"}]

as my output (which is correct in this case).

When using an array, the data autocompletes fine for the textbox.  Since this only happens on a datasource I suspect that getCountry.jsp isn't actually returning JSON data.  However, when I added

> response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

to the top of getCountry.jsp nothing still showed up and now I'm just stuck.

Comment: I would check your FireBug or Chrome JavaScript console to see if there are any exceptions being thrown. If the JSON is bad then you should bet getting an exception.

Comment: I don't see any exceptions thrown. =P

Comment: Do you see the http requests being made?

Comment: Hmm, no actually. I tried both my code and the one a-dilla suggested if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ah, that was dumb.  I fixed it by moving the javascript bit of code after I placed the textbox with id fromCountry. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the error, but I can share some useful links for you
[Auto complete using Scriptlets](http://wowjava.wordpress.com/2010/11/11/autocomplete-textbox-in-jsp/)  , 
[Auto complete in jsp](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/06/tutorial-create-autocomplete-feature-with-java-jsp-jquery.html) , 
[Auto complete in struts](http://roseindia.net/struts/struts2/struts2uitags/autocompleter-example.shtml) , 
[Auto populate](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/jquery/autoSuggestTextbox.html)